# Typesafe activator not working under corporate proxy

Tags: playframework, http-proxy, typesafe-activator, typesafe

I'm working with typesafe activator 1.3.5. I've downloaded it and configured the proxy as described [here](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/docs). When I try to create a new application I obtain this error:

```
[gaadmin@mypc scala-test]$ activator new test-app play-scala
Fetching the latest list of templates...

Aug 05, 2015 4:36:49 PM com.amazonaws.http.HttpClientFactory createHttpClient
INFO: Configuring Proxy. Proxy Host: isa.proxy Proxy Port: 8080
Aug 05, 2015 4:36:49 PM org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication process
SEVERE: Proxy authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt))
[Fatal Error] :2:18: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "http-equiv".
```

The password is correct as it works correctly in other application (live maven).

Do someone know how can I solve this problem?

Thanks,
Michele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've find out that the problem is related to the way activator communicates with Amazon S3. The workaround is to build directly with sbt and not with activator.

An issue has been raised: https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/1072